# Keeping everything on the left of the last '/' in Python

Tags: python, strsplit

I would like to keep everything to the left of the last '/' in a URL. I can keep everything to the right using the following:

```
"https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html".rsplit('/', 1).pop()
```

But, I want everything to the left. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part to the left of the last `/` is the first element of `"https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html".rsplit('/', 1)`, so:

```
>>> "https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html".rsplit('/', 1)[0]
'https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str="https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip/fedgfe.html"   
last_forward_slash_index=str.rfind('/')  #rfind() will find the last forward slash '/'
str1=str[0:last_forward_slash_index]
print(str1) # It will print "https://ideas.repec.org/s/fip"
```